# Incorrect data format for value - OrdType

Tags: python, quickfix, fix-protocol

I am using FIX 4.2 with QuickFix and python. I am connecting to CTS, a data provider who does everything in an odd way. I have been modifying my data dictionary for about 4 months (it's hell).

I have encountered a problem that I cannot fix by modifying the data dictionary, yet it appears to be a DD problem. I am very confused.

I send a SecurityDefinitionRequest, 35=c, and get a SecurityDefinition, 35=d, in return. Tag 40 has been heavily altered from the FIX protocol by CTS. http://www.ctsfutures.com/wiki/T4%20API%20FIX.Security%20Definition.ashx

I am trying to just define tag 40 as a string, and get on with it. But no matter what I do, my QF engine rejects the message with  **Incorrect data format for value:40**

Here is an example:

`(8=FIX.4.2☺9=591☺35=d☺34=15☺49=CTS☺56=XXX☺50=T4FIX☺52=20141111-15:56:11.62
7☺320=1415721370.22☺322=sd-11/11/2014 9:56:11 AM☺323=4☺911=12☺55=YM☺107=SIM:E-mi
ni Dow BF:+Dec14-2Mar15+Jun15☺48=XCME_E YM (Z14)-2(H15)(M15)☺

40=2083` **(<-- tag 40 is here)**

`☺207=CME_E☺200=201412☺205=19☺167=FUT☺762=4☺562=1☺15=USD☺1146=5☺5770=1/1☺555=3☺600=YM☺623=1☺624=1☺609=FUT☺602=XCME_E YM (Z14)☺556=USD☺610=201412☺616=CME_E☺620=SIM:E-mini Dow Dec14☺600=YM☺623=-2☺624=2☺609=FUT☺602=XCME_E YM (H15)☺556=USD☺610=201503☺616=CME_E☺620=SIM:E-mini Dow Mar15☺600=YM☺623=1☺624=1☺609=FUT☺602=XCME_E YM (M15)☺556=USD☺610=201506☺616=CME_E☺620=SIM:E-mini Dow Jun15☺10=235☺)`

`Incorrect data format for value: 2083
<20141111-15:56:11.087, FIX.4.2:XXX->CTS, event>
  (Message 15 Rejected: Incorrect data format for value:40)`

`<20141111-15:56:11.095, FIX.4.2:XXX->CTS, outgoing>
  (8=FIX.4.2☺9=114☺35=3☺34=23☺49=XXX☺52=20141111-15:56:11.095☺56=CTS☺45=15☺5
8=Incorrect data format for value☺371=40☺372=d☺373=6☺10=114☺)`

Here is the entry in my data dictionary:

```
<field number="40" name="OrdType" type="STRING"/>
```

Note that I have tried all kinds of combinations, like:

```
<field number="40" name="OrdType" type="STRING" allowOtherValues="true"/>
```

As well as explicitly specifying the problematic value

```
<field number="40" name="OrdType" type="STRING" >
    <value enum="2083" description="STUPID" />
</field>
```

Nothing ever works. I always get the same result. **Incorrect data format for value:40**

What's going on?!?

Comment: The `OrdType` field is defined as a `char` type, so I wonder if any multiple-character values work in the version of QuickFIX you're using. Out of curiosity, are you able to use any of CTS's non-standard `OrdType` values in any kind of message? For example, a `NewOrderSingle` (35=D) with `40=512` (GTC)? Or have you gotten any messages from CTS with any of the other custom `OrdType` values?

Comment: https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix/blob/3875882f490e96e721275dfffbbc8ae4b7da2308/src/python/quickfix_fields.py#L654

Comment: The [default FIX42.xml doc](http://www.quickfixengine.org/FIX42.xml) (for the version of QF I'm assuming you're using) defines `<field number="40" name="OrdType" type="CHAR">`.

Comment: VERY INTERESTING. I hadn't ever seen the code up there, and using the OrdType class built into QF seems to be my problem. I redefined tag 40 in my application to be a generic string and it fixed the problem straightaway. Want to distill the above into an answer below? You deserve internet points.

Comment: So nearly 9 years later, I ran into this issue with the CTS implementation with OrdType.  It uses totally different definitions in different messages: execution report and security definition.  Within the FIX42.xml, I changed the type to STRING, and at the same time removed the enum definitions.  Appears working.  Not sure if there will be further problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In QuickFIX, the [`OrdType` class](https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix/blob/3875882f490e96e721275dfffbbc8ae4b7da2308/src/python/quickfix_fields.py#L654) takes a `quickfix.CharField`:

```
class OrdType(quickfix.CharField):
    def __init__(self, data = None):
        if data == None:
            quickfix.CharField.__init__(self, 40)
        else:
            quickfix.CharField.__init__(self, 40, data)
```

The definition for `OrdType` in [the default FIX42.xml](http://www.quickfixengine.org/FIX42.xml) doc corroborates this:

`<field number="40" name="OrdType" type="CHAR">`

Thus, a `string` value for `OrdType` in an inbound FIX message will cause QuickFIX to reject the message for containing invalid data. You will need to modify QuickFIX to allow `string` values for `OrdType` to be able to accommodate inbound and outbound messages with the CTS custom values.